# CSVHelper says no map exists

Tags: c#, csv, dictionary, mapping, csvhelper

I'm trying to get CSVHelper to read some files, but it keeps telling me that no properties are mapped for my custom class. However, when I look with debugger it definitely seems like the Map is there and correct, so I'm confused.

Here's some code.

```
CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(ms));
csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
csv.Configuration.IsHeaderCaseSensitive = false;
csv.Configuration.SkipEmptyRecords = true;
csv.Configuration.TrimFields = true;
csv.Configuration.TrimHeaders = true;
csv.Configuration.WillThrowOnMissingField = false;
csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<SampleMap>();
readSamples = csv.GetRecords<Sample>().ToList(); //breaks here
```

Here's a truncated version of my Sample and SampleMap classes

```
namespace Parser.Models
{
    public class Sample
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public string Discussion { get; set; }
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class SampleMap : CsvClassMap<Sample>
    {
        public SampleMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.Discussion).Name("Cases::CaseDiscussion");
            Map(m => m.OrderNumber).Name("Orders::OrderNumber");
        }
    }
}
```

What's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fault is in my csv file, not my code. Please disregard. If you are having a similar issue, make sure to check your file. :)

Comment: Can I ask what your issue was please? I'm also stuck with everything looking very present and correct yet it won't map!

Comment: I've tried mapping by Index as well, eliminating spelling/spacing issues.

Comment: I was pointing to a .xmlx version of the file and not the .csv file, if memory serves. It's embarrassing.

Comment: Mine was having private setters in the classes I was mapping to! Wasted hours because of that.